# How to set Button Id's by Looping through Array of Id's and set button texts using loops as well?

Tags: java, android, button, for-loop

I am trying to set the id's of 5 (five) buttons programatically and shuffle them every time.
There's no problem with shuffle.
I get errors when I use 2 (two) methods that shuffles and set id of 5 buttons AND set the texts of each one.
I know this could be a mess because it's my first time to try for-each loop.
Please help. Thank you.

```
Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
Button[] buttons = { b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 };

    public void shuffleButtons() {

            Integer[] Id = { R.id.bChoice1, R.id.bChoice2, R.id.bChoice3,
                    R.id.bChoice4, R.id.bChoice5 };

            ArrayList<Integer> buttonId = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Id));

            Collections.shuffle(buttonId);


                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

                    for (Button b : buttons) {

                        b = (Button) findViewById(buttonId.get(x));

                    }

                }


        }
```

---

```
public void setButtonTxt() {


            for (Button b : buttons) {

                for (int x = 0; x <= buttons.length; x++) {

                    b.setText(textList.get(x));

                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use a listView instead? It might be a better fit for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I'm guessing your issue is `x <= buttons.length` should be `x < buttons.length` in your for loop. However it looks like you're going to set all 5 buttons to `textList.get(5)` with the current code you have.

Why not try with preset buttons in XML?

```
<Button android:id="@+id/bChoice1" ... />
<!-- etc -->
<Button android:id="@+id/bChoice5" ... />
```

Then in the code behind, randomize the text instead of both?

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bChoice1);
Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bChoice2);
Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bChoice3);
Button b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bChoice4);
Button b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bChoice5);

// assuming textList is an ArrayList of text items
// the next two lines will randomize your textList order
// so you don't need to do it yourself and much less
// error-prone
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(textList, new Random(seed));

b1.setText(textList.get(0));
b2.setText(textList.get(1));
b3.setText(textList.get(2));
b4.setText(textList.get(3));
b5.setText(textList.get(4));
```

Comment: okay. i'll try that. thanks!
BTW, i didn't get that 'long' variable along with the collections. those two lines of codes.

Comment: Added a comment in. It's basically randomizing the order of the textList ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to set the id's of 5 (five) buttons programatically and
>   shuffle them every time. There's no problem with shuffle.

My suggestion is that you shoudn't, musn't do it. Each id should be created from `XML` and then each is automatic generated in `R.java` as static int field.

You should respect this rule and don't create "spaghetti code".

Answer (score 0):

it's better for you to write your code in this way :

```
Button [] buttens=new Button[5];
final int ID= R.id.bChoice1;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        button[i]=(Button)findViewById(ID+i);
    }
```

but be careful it works as long as you set your button id's consecutively !